# How to run Prometheus Ruby Client

Tags: ruby, prometheus

I want to run the Prometheus Ruby Client, to gather statistics values and to save in the Prometheus database.

I've followed the instructions here : Rack middleware 
https://github.com/prometheus/client_ruby#rack-middleware

I've installed two gems, `prometheus` and `prometheus-client`.

The **exporter.rb** (https://github.com/prometheus/client_ruby/blob/master/lib/prometheus/middleware/exporter.rb) and the **collector.rb** (https://github.com/prometheus/client_ruby/blob/master/lib/prometheus/middleware/collector.rb) is saved in the location: `prometheus/middleware`

I've saved the **config.ru** (https://github.com/prometheus/client_ruby#rack-middleware) in the local folder.

Then I've started the rack web server with: `rackup -d config.ru -I /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/prometheus-client-0.6.0/lib -I /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/quantile-0.2.0/lib`

The -I include statement is necessary to let find the required files.

Then I got this error :

```
/home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/prometheus-client-0.6.0/lib -I /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/quantile-0.2.0/lib
nil
Exception `ArgumentError' at /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:86 - wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
Exception `ArgumentError' at /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49 - wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
Exception `ArgumentError' at /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/rackup:22 - wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
/home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/deflater.rb:20:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:86:in `new'
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:86:in `block in use'
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `block in to_app'
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `each'
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `inject'
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `to_app'
    from /home/sven/StarPerfMonitor_v2.0.0/config.ru:13:in `<main>'
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:242:in `start'
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/rackup:22:in `load'
    from /home/sven/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/rackup:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you please to complete error message including the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `client_ruby 0.6.0` whereas `Prometheus::Middleware` is available only for `client_ruby 0.7.0`.

Check https://github.com/prometheus/client_ruby/tree/v0.6.0

Answer (score 0):

This issue was too tricky, and I decided to switch over to InfluxDB. 
And I was able to run the Ruby Client within minutes. It seems to be much more better for me, than Prometheus. Sorry.